# No way to avoid SLF4J error in maven

Tags: maven, logging, tomcat7, slf4j, logback

I know this has been asked before but none of the answers has worked for me yet. I get the error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I've allready tryed to use:

- **Only slf4j-api**
- slf4j-api and log4j
- slf4j-api, jcl-over-slf4j, log4j
- **Only slf4j-log4j12**
- slf4j-log4j12 and log4j
- **Only logback-classic**
- logback-classic and logback-core
- slf4j-api, logback-classic and logback-core
- [log4j-api 2, log4j-core 2, log4j-slf4j-impl](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html)
- [log4j-over-slf4j, jul-to-slf4j, logback-classic](http://blog.frankel.ch/configuring-maven-to-use-slf4j)
- [slf4j-api, logback-classic](http://blog.frankel.ch/configuring-maven-to-use-slf4j)

For each one I've tried with the tutorial/answer version and the latest (`mvn versions:use-latest-version`)

Since there are some answers arround there that tells you can only have one of those libraries on your classpath I remark that I've already tryed em.

Also I've used a `log4j.properties` inside `src/main/resources/` like this one:

```
# Set root logger level and appender name.
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, file

# Specify appenders.
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

# Configure console appender.
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n

# Configure file appender.
log4j.appender.file.File = /webapp/logs/web.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n
```

And a `logback.xml` at the same place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>silkroad.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.base22" level="ALL"/>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is the code I've tried out:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {

    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.debug("Testing the log");

    } 
}
```

Appart from the loggin dependences I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've followed several tutorials (12~15) using different ways of geting the log facade working, including the ones on theyr sites without success.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works for a project I have.  I am using log4j 1, a standard log4j.xml file.  I also had to exclude `commons-logging` from any dependency that includes it, e.g. `spring-core` as shown.

```
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        ....
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: See the `<properties>` section in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway it didn't work neither with yours nor the latest slf4 version (1.7.7)

Comment: Have you made sure that none of the other logging dependencies (including commons-logging and other slf4j artifacts) are being pulled in transitively?

Comment: Are you deploying your app to a web container, or is this a standalone test app?

Comment: It's a webapp. I deploy it to Tomcat using `mvn tomcat7:deploy. It packages a `.war` file.

Comment: Web containers often provide libraries on the classpath.  I don't know how Tomcat 7 does it, but in WebLogic I have to have explicit configuration telling WebLogic to use classes on my app's classpath instead of those provided by the container.  Every web container does classpathing a little differently.  I would make sure there isn't a conflict between your classpath and Tomcat's.

Comment: I just checked one of our webapps, and indeed, slf4j and log4j are in the `prefer-application-packages` config needed by WebLogic.

Comment: apache-tomcat says It's only needed to change tomcat configuration in order to use log4j instead of the default for the tomcat internal loggin.